# Basic chat in Gtk

Tags: c, gtk

So, I have three labels and 1 entry box. My goal is to have every time you type into the entry box and press enter, the text appears in the third label. If you do this again, the text appears in the third label and the old text gets moved into the second label, and so on (so the labels display the last three messages you typed.)

```
Here is the ChatInfo Struct:

typedef struct chat_info ChatInfo;
struct chat_info {
GtkWidget *text_line1;
GtkWidget *text_line2;
GtkWidget *text_line3;
GtkWidget *entry;

};
```

Here is the function that initializes the chat box:

```
static void get_chatbox(GtkWidget ** vbox, gpointer data) {

GuiInfo *g = (GuiInfo *) data;

ChatInfo *c;
c = (ChatInfo *) malloc(sizeof(ChatInfo));

g->chat = c;

GtkWidget *text_line1;
GtkWidget *text_line2;
GtkWidget *text_line3;

GtkWidget *entry;
GtkEntryBuffer *buffer;

text_line1 = gtk_label_new("");
text_line2 = gtk_label_new("");
text_line3 = gtk_label_new("");

buffer = gtk_entry_buffer_new(NULL, -1);
entry = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(buffer);


gtk_entry_set_activates_default(GTK_ENTRY(entry), TRUE);


gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), entry, FALSE, FALSE, 1);
gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), text_line3, FALSE, FALSE, 1);
gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), text_line2, FALSE, FALSE, 1);
gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), text_line1, FALSE, FALSE, 1);


gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) text_line1, .01, .5);
gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) text_line2, .01, .5);
gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) text_line3, .01, .5);
gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) entry, .01, .5);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(send_message), g);
}
```

Here is the callback:

```
static void send_message(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data){
GuiInfo *g = (GuiInfo *) data;


ChatInfo *c = g->chat;

const gchar *message = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(c->entry));

const gchar *oldtext3 = gtk_label_get_text(c->text_line3);
const gchar *oldtext2 = gtk_label_get_text(c->text_line2);



gtk_label_set_text(c->text_line3, message);
gtk_label_set_text(c->text_line2, oldtext3);
gtk_label_set_text(c->text_line1, oldtext2);


}
```

I'm getting a seg fault with this line, and not sure why:

const gchar *message = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(c->entry));

Answer (score 3):

You malloc c and you `gtk_label_new` your text_line1 etc...
but you never do

```
c->text_line1 = text_line1;
```

in `get_chatbox()`
and I think it's the same for entry :)

so you use an unitialized value when you use c->entry

so the result is

```
static void get_chatbox(GtkWidget ** vbox, gpointer data)
{
     GuiInfo*        g = (GuiInfo*)data;
     ChatInfo*       c;
     GtkWidget*      text_line1;
     GtkWidget*      text_line2;
     GtkWidget*      text_line3;
     GtkWidget*      entry;
     GtkEntryBuffer* buffer;

     c = malloc(sizeof(*ChatInfo));
     g->chat = c;
     text_line1 = gtk_label_new("");
     text_line2 = gtk_label_new("");
     text_line3 = gtk_label_new("");
     buffer = gtk_entry_buffer_new(NULL, -1);
     entry = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(buffer);
     gtk_entry_set_activates_default(GTK_ENTRY(entry), TRUE);
     //------MY ADD-------
     c->text_line1 = text_line1;
     c->text_line2 = text_line2;
     c->text_line3 = text_line3;
     c->entry = entry;
     //-------------------

     gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), entry, FALSE, FALSE, 1);
     gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), text_line3, FALSE, FALSE, 1);
     gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), text_line2, FALSE, FALSE, 1);
     gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(*vbox), text_line1, FALSE, FALSE, 1);


     gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) text_line1, .01, .5);
     gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) text_line2, .01, .5);
     gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) text_line3, .01, .5);
     gtk_misc_set_alignment((GtkMisc *) entry, .01, .5);
     g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(send_message), g);
}
```

Comment: You may also use `c = g_new (ChatInfo,1)` instead of `c = (ChatInfo *) malloc(sizeof(ChatInfo));` which makes allocation a little less cumbersome to type.

Answer (score 1):

In get_chatbox you locally declare:

```
GtkWidget *text_line1;
GtkWidget *text_line2;
GtkWidget *text_line3;

GtkWidget *entry;
```

I think you mean to reference the members of c, so you wouldn't need to declare these local variables, and instead use:

```
c->text_line1 = gtk_label_new("");
c->text_line2 = gtk_label_new("");
c->text_line3 = gtk_label_new("");

c->entry = gtk_entry_new_with_buffer(buffer);
```